# Showing multiple Line Legends in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to display all 4 legends of my line graph, with the Column headers serving as the respective Legend names.
Is there an elegant way of executing this without having to write individual lines  of code to plot and label each column?

Examples of my current data set are as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
y.columns = ["A","B","C","D"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
ax.plot(x, y, label=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can use the plot function defined in pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
y.columns = ["A","B","C","D"]
y['x'] = x
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
y.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image: Output image]